# show hyperlink only for a certain user's posts

Tags: php, session

I have a *posts* table like this:

```
post_id            user_id       title            date
   12                  1           abc          7/20/2014
   13                  1           cde          7/21/2014
   14                  2           fgh          7/22/2014
```

And a *users* table like this:

```
user_id          username         email                    password
   1               name1          email1@domain.com         ******
   2               name2          email2@domain.com         ******
```

The *user_id* in the *posts* table is the foreign key of the *users* table.

Note:

Assume that I store the user's session successfully by using `$_SESSION['user_id']` .

Assume that I can echo all 3 post titles along with their usernames successfully too.

Now I would like to **echo** the *edit* hyperlink **(`<a href="edit.com">Edit</a>`)** for the post titles of a certain user, for example, `user_id 1 or 2` after he's logged in. It means that if the user named `name1` signs into his account and browses the post whose id is 14, he cannot see the *edit* hyperlink because it belongs to the another user named `name2`, whose session id, if any, should be unableable now, and vice versa.

For me, this is my code:

```
$q = "SELECT title, post_id, p.user_id AS currentuser
      FROM posts AS p
      INNER JOIN users AS u USING (user_id)
      ORDER BY date ASC
      ";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$uid = isset($_SESSION['user_id']);// variable for the seesion

$current_user = $row['currentuser'];// variable for the certain user ID

          if($uid && $uid == $current_user){      
              echo "<a href=\"http://edit.com\"> Edit </a></div>";
            }
```

Then I test it, you know, it shows the *edit* hyperlink in every post title, but not what i expected.

Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uid = isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
```

This results to either true or false. try

```
$uid = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : -1;
```

What I did was use a ternary operator so if the session variable is set, you set it to it otherwise you set it to -1, which most probably does not exsist in a table id column